# PHP will not delete from MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

For some reason, JavaScript/PHP wont delete my data from MySQL! Here is the rundown of the problem.

---

I have an array that displays all my MySQL entries in a nice format, with a button to delete the entry for each one individually. It looks like this:

```
<?php

            include("login.php");

        //connection to the database
        $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
         or die("<br/><h1>Unable to connect to MySQL, please contact support at support@michalkopanski.com</h1>");

        //select a database to work with
        $selected = mysql_select_db($dbname, $dbhandle)
          or die("Could not select database.");

        //execute the SQL query and return records
        if (!$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `url` FROM `videos`"))
        echo 'mysql error: '.mysql_error();

        //fetch tha data from the database
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
           ?>

       <div class="video"><a class="<?php echo $row{'id'}; ?>" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?php echo $row{'url'}; ?>">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?php echo $row{'url'}; ?></a><a class="del" href="javascript:confirmation(<? echo $row['id']; ?>)">delete</a></div>

<?php }

//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

The delete button has an href of `javascript:confirmation(<? echo $row['id']; ?>)` , so once you click on delete, it runs this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function confirmation(ID) {
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this video?")
    if (answer){
        alert("Entry Deleted")
        window.location = "delete.php?id="+ID;
    }
    else{
        alert("No action taken")
    }
}
//-->
</script>
```

The JavaScript should theoretically pass the 'ID' onto the page delete.php. That page looks like this (and I think this is where the problem is):

```
<?php

include ("login.php");

mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

mysql_select_db ($dbname)
or die("Unable to connect to database");

mysql_query("DELETE FROM `videos` WHERE `videos`.`id` ='.$id.'");
echo ("Video has been deleted.");
?>
```

If there's anyone out there that may know the answer to this, I would greatly appreciate it. I am also opened to suggestions (for those who aren't sure).

Thanks!

Comment: Try some simple debugging techniques: output the ID from delete.php to see if it's being received as you expected.

Comment: +1 for detailed source code and a well written question.

Comment: @harto: Yea, I would usually do that, but I was so frustrated that it didn't even cross my mind. It's been screwing with me for a good 30 minutes!

@MitMaro: Thank you! I appreciate it, and I hope other readers can learn something from this question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your `delete.php` script, you are using this line :

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `videos` WHERE `videos`.`id` ='.$id.'");
```

The `$id` variable doesn't exists : you must initialize it from the `$_GET` variable, like this :

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

*(This is because your page is called using an HTTP GET request -- ie, parameters are passed in the URL)*

Also, your query feels quite strange : what about this instead :

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `videos` WHERE `videos`.`id` = '$id' ");
```

ie, removing the '`.`' : you are inside a string already, so there is nothing to concatenate *(the [dot operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) in PHP is for concatenation of strings)*

Note :

- if this works on some server, it is probably because of [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals)

  - For more informations, see [Using Register Globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)
  - But note that this "feature" has been deprecated, and should definitely not be used !

    - It causes security risks
    - And should disappear in PHP 6 -- that'll be a nice change, even if it breaks a couple of old applications
- your code has a big [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) hole : you should sanitize/filter/escape the `$id` before using it in a query !

  - If you `video.id` is a string, this means using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

    - If you where using the mysqli or PDO extensions, you could also take a look at prepared statements
  - with an integer, you might call `intval` to make sure you actually get an integer.

So, in the end, I would say you should use something that looks like this :

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$escaped_id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$query = "DELETE FROM `videos` WHERE `videos`.`id` = '$escaped_id'";
// Here, if needed, you can output the $query, for debugging purposes
mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to delimit your query string very strangely... this is what you want:

```
mysql_query('DELETE FROM `videos` WHERE `videos`.`id` ='.$id);
```

But make sure you sanitize/validate `$id` before you query!

**Edit:** And as Pascal said, you need to assign `$id = $_GET['id'];`. I overlooked that.

Comment: Thanks, you were on the right track, but the query wasn't working, even with the $_GET request.

The correct query was `mysql_query("DELETE FROM `videos` WHERE `videos`.`id` = $id ");`

Comment: sorry, it got all screwed up, here it is:

mysql_query("DELETE FROM `videos` WHERE `videos`.`id` = $id ");

Comment: okay, so i don't how to add code into comments, here is a last attempt:

<code>mysql_query("DELETE FROM `videos` WHERE `videos`.`id` = $id ");</code>

Answer (score 0):

In your delete.php you never set $id.

You need to check the value in $_REQUEST['id'] (or other global variable) and ONLY if it's an integer, set $id to that.

EDIT: Oh, also you need to remove the periods before and after $id in the query. You should print out your query so you can see what you're sending to the sql server. Also, you can get the SQL server's error message.

Answer (score 0):

You add extra dots in the string.
Use

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `videos` WHERE `videos`.`id` ='$id'");
```

instead of

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `videos` WHERE `videos`.`id` ='.$id.'");
```

Also check how do you get the value of `$id`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I used [Pascal MARTIN's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138475/pascal-martin) answer, and it comes to show that I was missing the request (`$_GET`) to get the 'id' from the precious page, and that some of my query was incorrect.

Here is the working copy:

```
<?php

include ("login.php");

$id = $_GET['id'];

mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

mysql_select_db ($dbname)
or die("Unable to connect to database");

mysql_query("DELETE FROM `videos` WHERE `videos`.`id` = $id ");
echo ("Video ".$id." has been deleted.");
?>
```

Thanks again!